# Доступ к консоли Linux через беседу в VK (Kali Rasp PI)

Tags: vkontakte-api, ssh, raspberry-pi, kali-linux

Мне нужен доступ к консоли Kali из беседы VK. Kali весит на rasp pi 4, а малина дома. Мне это надо чтобы я и мои друзья могли юзать кали удалённо или объясните как сделать ssh не локальным. Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> как сделать ssh не локальным.

Для этого нужно выполнение двух условий:

1. Ваш домашний комп должен иметь либо статический IP, либо зарегистрированное DNS-имя.
2. Ваш файрволл, который запущен (почти наверняка) на домашнем роутере пропускает входящие SSH запросы.

Если Вы можете это организовать, то имеет смысл говорить о дальнейшем.

Comment: Как это все сделать и проверить пропускает ли файрволл SSH запросы ?

Comment: @Matthew  Статический IP - это договор с интернет-провайдером. Файрволл на роутере - открывайте инструкцию на роутер и смотрите IP, логин и пароль по умолчанию. Адрес роутера, скорее всего буде 192.168.0.1

Comment: Понятно договор с интернет-провайдером не доступен